# Prevent browser from scrolling up when Bootstrap carousel changes slide

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a VueJS app with a page that contains seven small carousels (Pink boxes - using [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org)). Each carousel contains a number of slide (One product per slide).

Below that (Green boxes) is a list of different combinations that can be made (Each green box is a unique combination).

When I click a combination it sets each carousel to the correct product/slide.
The problem is, if you click one of the green boxes to set the combination (this works fine), and the page is scrolled down, the page automatically scrolls up to the carousel that changes.
I suspect the way I am setting the slide in the carousel brings it in to focuse and foces the browser to scroll up (Firefox).

**Question:** How do I prevent the browser from scrolling up when I click on one of the combinations?
(I would like to keep the browser in the same position)

[image]

The template for my carousel looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="b-capsule-layer">

    <b-carousel id="carousel1"
      ref="layerCarousel"
      :controls="showControls"
      :interval="0"
      v-model="slide"
      @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
      @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
      @mouseenter.native="toggleHover"
      @mouseleave.native="toggleHover"
    >

      <b-carousel-slide
        v-for="(product, index) in sortedBySequence(layer)"
        class="p-3"
        :key="product.id"
        :img-src="product.image_urls[0]"
        :data-product-id="product.id"
        :data-product-index="index"
        v-on:click.native="clickProductSlide($event, product)"
      >
        <div class="brand">{{product.brand_name}}</div>
        <div class="price">{{ formattedPrice(product) }}</div>
      </b-carousel-slide>

    </b-carousel>
  </div>
</template>
```

In the carousel componenet I have a data value called `selectedProductId` (Each slide is a different product).
I have a watcher setup to listen to changes to `selectedProductId`, and if a change is made it changes the carousel to the correct slide.

My watcher looks like this:

```
watch: {
  layerProducts: function(newVal, oldVal) {
    this.setSelectedProduct();
  },

  selectedProductId: function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if ( newVal !== null || newVal == oldVal) {
      const el = document.querySelector(`[data-product-id='${newVal}']`);

      if (el && !el.classList.contains('active')) {
        this.slide = parseInt(el.dataset['productIndex']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The value of `selectedProductId` is set when the carousel's parent component makes changes to `layerProducts` (This change is triggered in the first watcher above).

Comment: I'm not from Vue world but have you tried e.prevent.default ?

Comment: I tried using `prevent` on click of the combination box (green) but that doesn't seem to be the problem. The issue seems to occur when i assign the index to the carousel, here `this.slide = parseInt(el.dataset['productIndex']);` but I'm not sure how, or if it's even possible to get the event when doing this. :/

Comment: could you share  the code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)

Comment: Hmmm sharing the code is proving to be quite difficult since there are quite a few moving parts :| I'll try get it up though

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest versions of Vue and BootstrapVue.